# Cast type at index time of document

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Once ES has dynamically mapped a type to a specific field, is it possible to automatically cast all future values to this type?

Specifically, I want to do this as part of my bulk upload. I don't care if there's data loss- I just don't want to bother with explicitly defining a mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch will try to coerce things (mostly for numbers), but it'll ultimately reject documents that don't match the mapping